# Laplace's Equation Symbol

Tags: symbols, greek

I used `\nabla` to present the laplace equation but it doesn't work, is there any method to write the del operator (Gradient) symbol?

Comment: Load `amsmath` package.

Comment: Can you show an example of non working code?

Comment: You mean `\nabla^2` hopefully for the laplace operator? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes :D

Comment: @Sigur, actually I want to write it on a physics.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: @egreg the result is \nabla

Comment: @A.khalaf `\nabla` goes in a math formula, so between `$` symbols.

Comment: @egreg I know, and I did it !! but still \nabla !!

Comment: according to [the mathjax supported symbol list](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands) `\nabla` should work with mathjax.

Comment: Oh !! I have a mistake, sorry all it is work :D

Comment: @A.khalaf: I just typed `$\nabla^2$ in a Physics.SX question window... it shows the correct symbol(s)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ya it is work, there was a stupid mistake !! , I'm so sorry for that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MathJax.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

here an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \nabla (fg)= f\nabla g + g \nabla f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

it yields:

[image]

if this does not work there must e something wrong with your TeX installation.

Comment: This is nice, but the question itself is 'off-topic', since it is concerned with a) a typo on Physics.SX and b) mathjax - related